# Getting error: NameError: name 'filelist' is not defined >>>

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

Getting error:

> NameError: name 'filelist' is not defined >>>

Code:

```
>import re 
>import os
>def file_rename ():
>filelist = os.listdir(r"D:\movies")
>savedpath=os.getcwd()
>print("current working directory is"+savedpath)
>print (filelist)
>os.chdir(r"D:\movies")
>for filename in filelist:
>new_name = re.sub('[0-9]', '', filename)
>print (new_name)
file_rename ()
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what do you want to do exactly.
because your write a code with wrong syntactic.
but i think your code near it:

```
import re 
import os

def file_rename ():
    filelist = os.listdir(r"/home/omilun/Desktop/")
    savedpath = os.getcwd()
    print("current working directory is"+savedpath)
    print(filelist)
    os.chdir(r"/home/omilun/Desktop")
    for filename in filelist:
        new_name = re.sub('[0-9]', '', filename)
        print(new_name)

file_rename ()
```

you should give `absolute address`. i know Unix and i use Unix directory address . you can change both of them with your absolute address on windows .

Comment: What is wrong with the address I have provided for windows 10?  I just copied the address from the menu.

Comment: This program is supposed to rename(remove numbers at the start of filename) a bunch of files in a folder .

Comment: Ok got it. I just changed the path. But still getting the same error.

Comment: import re
import os
def file_rename ():
     filelist = 0
     os.chdir (r"C:\Users\adith_000\Desktop\smallprank")
     filelist = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\adith_000\Desktop\smallprank")
     print("before rename"+ filelist)
     filelist = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\adith_000\Desktop\smallprank")
for filename in filelist:
    
    new_name = re.sub('[0-9]','', filename)
    print (new_name)
savedpath=os.getcwd()
print("current dir is "+savedpath)
file_rename()

Comment: i told you about absolute address dude.